# binding values submitted from a View to a Controller

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-basic-app

I am coding a form to get user input and then pass that information to a controller and execute a function based on that, at this point I can not pass the data to the controller using POST method, I get empty vars.

So the Controller function display the view form correctly, I can type on the textboxes, after press submit button I get a setFlash custom message that the parameters are empty. I am using a model class with just two parameters.

a) This is the model:

```php
<?php
namespace app\models;
use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class SendmailForm extends Model
{
    public $template;
    public $emtransport;


    /**
     * @return array the validation rules.
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['template', 'emtransport'], 'required'],
        ];
    }

}
```

b) This is the view:

```php
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\captcha\Captcha;

$this->title = 'Send Mail';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="site-contact">
    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

    <?php if (Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('sminfo')): ?>
        <div class="alert alert-success">
            <?= Yii::$app->session->getFlash('sminfo');?>
        </div>

    <?php else: ?>

        <p>
            SendMail Exercise. Please choose needed options bellow:
        </p>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">

                <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'sendmail-form']); ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'template')->textInput(['autofocus' => true]) ?>

                    <?= $form->field($model, 'emtransport') ?>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= Html::submitButton('Submit', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'value'=>'one', 'name'=>'sendbtn']) ?>
                    </div>

                <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>

            </div>
        </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

And this is the controller's function:

```php
public function actionSendmail(){
        $model = new SendmailForm();                        
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $template = Yii::$app->request->post('template');
            $emailTransport = Yii::$app->request->post("emtransport");
            if($emailTransport=="local"){
                for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
                    $xclient = 'client' . $i;
                    \app\models\User::findByUsername($xclient)->sendMail($template, 'Welcome To XYZ Services', ['accountInfo' => 'www.mysite.com']);
                }//end of for loop
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash("sminfo", "Emails sent successfully to the Clients");
                return $this->refresh();                
            }//end of second if loop
            else{
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash("sminfo", "Params could not be verified!. Contact Tech Support");
                return $this->refresh();                                
            }

        }//end of post if loop

        return $this->render('sendmail', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

The idea is to get the values from the view, at this moment I am getting empty values-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two parts below:

```
$template = Yii::$app->request->post('template');
$emailTransport = Yii::$app->request->post("emtransport");
```

Change the following:

```
$template = $model->template;
$emailTransport = $model->emtransport;
```

---

**After editing**

```
public function actionSendmail(){
        $model = new SendmailForm();                        
        if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
            $template = $model->template;
            $emailTransport = $model->emtransport;
            if($emailTransport=="local"){
                for($i=0;$i<=2;$i++){
                    $xclient = 'client' . $i;
                    \app\models\User::findByUsername($xclient)->sendMail($template, 'Welcome To XYZ Services', ['accountInfo' => 'www.mysite.com']);
                }//end of for loop
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash("sminfo", "Emails sent successfully to the Clients");
                return $this->refresh();                
            }//end of second if loop
            else{
                Yii::$app->session->setFlash("sminfo", "Params could not be verified!. Contact Tech Support");
                return $this->refresh();                                
            }

        }//end of post if loop

        return $this->render('sendmail', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I did some changes to the Controller and now it works, those are them:

```php
//at the beginning of the Controller:
use app\models\SendmailForm;

//two lines changed in the function:
            $model->template = $_POST['SendmailForm']['template'];
            $model->emtransport = $_POST['SendmailForm']['emtransport'];
```

That's all I needed. Best regards